# Could you make my sentences more natural? If I misuse some words, plz which is wrong

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure

1. homage
   ex1) Joe SeHo showed homage towards Yu Jaeseok. he said "when I had money problems, he helped me without paybacks".

- Q1. What's the difference between "to" and "towards"?

ex2) Many pick YuJaeseok as a homage. Because he donated a lot and helped younger friends when they told concerns."

2. Plagiarism
   ex1)
   A: Hey, It's really yours? not a plagiarism?
   B: absolutely, why?
   A: a few days ago, I saw that Jeff presented her artworks in public. It's really similar to yours.
   B: Just because looking someone else's artwork, don't judge I copied with it. It's annoying

-Q1. When do you guys use 'absolutely' as an answer?

ex2)
Personally, art fields have controversy about plagiarism compared to others. Do you think so?

Comment: Please ask only one question in a post. You should break this post down into individual questions. Also, please take a [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and see how this site works. Take a minute to study well received questions and see how they are written.

Comment: _Homage_ means a formal demonstration of respect for a distinguished person. Neither of yuour examples uses the word correctly.

Comment: thx for commenting Eddie Kal! I use this site lately, and don't see how this site works. Next time, I'll look for similar questions at first, and then I'll post on what I wonder!

Comment: Thx Kate Bunting! the word that you mention was the first. I'll write it down:)) have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my explanations:

> Q1. What's the difference between "to" and "towards"?

The meaning of "towards" is "in the direction of" according to the dictionary. So it could be used like "He is running towards the car" which means "He is running in the direction of the car". Whereas "to" could be used like "He gave this to me", "to you" really is just like "for you" or "at you"/

> Q1. When do you guys use "absolutely" as an answer?

The meaning of "absolutely" is "with no qualification, restriction, or limitation; totally." as mentioned in the dictionary, "absolutely" literally just means "totally", "completely" or "definitely". As mentioned in the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/absolutely), there is an example sentence of: "Can you lend me $10 till tomorrow?" "Absolutely, it’s no problem.", so "absolutely" just is another way of saying "definitely", "totally" or "completely".

Comment: Thx for teaching! I want to use this word in daily conversation but I feel like it's awkward saying. I totally understand:))

Comment: @yeon._.chu Your welcome, remember to upvote and accept :-)\